# jQuery Ajax doesn't always send request to server

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

So, I have this link, that should send an AJAX request everytime it is clicked:

```
<a href="/application/start_game?human_is_first=true" data-remote="true">Yes</a>
```

But, it doesn't always work the first try. And sometimes, it will work only after other AJAX links are clicked (which also don't send requests when they should).

I know that the link is sending requests, because the server console output doesn't change when I click the link. No errors, nothing.

I am using [`rails.js`](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) and jQuery 1.4.4.

Live app to show you what is going on: http://ttt-ai.heroku.com/

Comment: What does it mean, "doesn't work on the first try"? It takes you away from the page? Then you use "Back" in the browser and then it works? Most importantly—which browser are you using? How do you suggest we go about reproducing this?

Comment: @mislav: AFAIK, `rails.js` binds a click handler to `a[data-remote]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the JavaScript on the page; only with your poor CSS.

You see, in your whole "Yes" and "No" buttons, the actual link element occupies only the tiny amount of space directly around the letters. The link has absolutely no padding and is therefore easy to miss when clicking on the button.

Because you created ":hover" style on the LI element itself, you gave us the impression that the whole element reacts to clicks. It does not. Only the A element reacts to clicks and is handled by rails.js.

Comment: lol, thats what I get for using someone else's buttons. Thanks =p

Answer (score 1):

A common issue is that javascript is not loaded in time, or is loaded at the wrong time (i.e before the dom is ready). Are there any errors in the JS error log?

Comment: I added a link if you want to check it out.

Comment: It seems that he loads all javascripts in the HEAD, meaning there's no way scripts are not executed yet.

Comment: @DerNalia - there are not JS errors that I can see, I looked at the page in firebug, it is all done correctly in JS. The link always worked for me. I think Mislav has it right.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you using firebug with firequery (Firefox addons).
Then you can see the binded jquery events and ajax requests outgoing from the browser.
Often this helps to understand why something doesn't work.
Check in the firebug console that your ajax request is properly send, if not, check if the click event on the link is binded.

Comment: firebug console shows no js activity when i click the buttons. (at least not after a while.)

Comment: I added a link if you want to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Along with @ispum's suggestions to check the bound events in firebug/other debugger also check to make sure that the `ajax:before` callback is not canceling your event:

```
  $("#your_link_id")
    .bind('ajax:before', function() { 
       //if this returns false, remote event is cancelled 
     });
```

is not returning `false`, which will cancel the remote action

Comment: I added a link if you want to check it out.

Comment: Note: the "ajax:before" event is now called "ajax:beforeSend".